# Seeking children's record with American Indian story about a giant with a frozen heart

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, audio-book

I had a children's LP record that had some American Indian stories on it.  As I recall, there was a frame narrative about a grandfather telling the stories to his grandchildren in the present day (meaning some time from the 1960s to 1980s, although the copy of the record I had was probably pressed in the 1970s or 1980s).  I'd like to find it again (an online recording, if possible), but I only recall one of the stories.

The story was about a prehuman race of giants, who were driven north when humans arrived on the scene.  There, in the arctic, they froze and became ice beings.  However, they eventually came south again; the unfroze, except for their hearts.  To prepare to make war against the humans, they rolled in sand, which made their skins hard and scaly.  However, all but one of them were defeated in a great battle.

The last giant escaped and menaced the people for many years afterwards.  Finally, as he was waiting to ambush a young man's camp one night, the giant waited too long near the fire, and his heart melted again.

Comment: I can't find any album, but the giant race with the frozen hearts is the [Chenoo](http://www.native-languages.org/chenoo.htm), windigo, a few other names.

Comment: @JohnP For what it's worth, I do not think that name was used on the record.

Comment: Probably a different tribe, then. The link has 3 or 4 other names, but they are all the ice giants with frozen hearts. That's the only reference I could find to that type of monster in Native American legends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer came to me.  The record was called "The Last of the Mohegans" (It was spelled that way, I believe—not "Mohicans" as in the famous James Fenimore Cooper novel.)  The front of the sleeve had a pastel drawing showing two children, a brother and sister, sitting in the back seat of a 1950s-style convertible.  I tried to find an image, but there are so many things out there (including quite a few albums) using the name "The Last of the Mohicans," that this obscure bit does not apparently show up.

My mother refused to believe me when I said that the story had nothing to do with Natty Bumpo.  (I had watched a television adaptation of the *Leatherstocking Tales*, so I knew more or less what to expect from Cooper.)  It was just the old Mohegan grandfather telling tribal stories to his grandchildren.  It wasn't a bad record, but it was clearly trying to cash in on the famous (although well over a century old) name.  (I had another record called "JAWS of the Shark," which was of a similar nature; it had nothing to do with the Spielberg movie.)